# How do I know which nvidia driver to install for FreeBSD?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, freebsd, display-driver

The tutorial I'm following says to download the driver that corresponds to my system, but I don't know which one that is. I'm using a GTX 1050 ti.

[image]

Comment: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us so probably https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/191963/en-us/

Comment: @Gantendo Awesome, but how do I download it? I don't exactly have access to a web browser at this stage in the setup

Comment: use `curl https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/FreeBSD-x86_64/515.65.01/NVIDIA-FreeBSD-x86_64-515.65.01.tar.xz --output driver.tar.xz` But if curl isn't installed you can use `sudo pkg install curl` and then the command above.

Comment: how do I install it? This only downloads, right?

Comment: @Badasahog Aha, right. You have internet access to ask questions here so definitely you can read this by itself   ADDITIONAL INFORMATION at https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DO NOT INSTALL DRIVERS DIRECTLY FROM NVIDIA! You are most likely to have issues. [The Handbook gives instructions](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/x11/#x-config-video-cards) on how to install the proper packages or ports. ALWAYS follow the handbook!

Your board needs the standard x11/nvidia-driver. So to install it do:

```
pkg install x11/nvidia-driver
```